'Authorization required' trying to use Chromium
I just installed Chromium on Debian 12 (always used FF till now).  When I try to run it as root it seems this is required:
chromium --no-sandbox
... but then it complains that '--no-sandbox' is not supported (even tho it's required.) ... but it seems to run fine just the same.
Running as a regular account I get this:
$ chromium
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified

[5605:5605:0827/081107.955032:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(244)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[5605:5605:0827/081107.955174:ERROR:env.cc(258)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.

... dunno why it complains about the X server, as noted, it runs as root.

This did it.  As root:
% xhost + local:
